# My device's hotspot got unlimited range

Tags: wi-fi, huawei, wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering

Today after leaving home by taxi I decided to find out when my laptop would lose connection to my phone's hotspot and was very surprised. It looked like my laptop way staying connected despite the further I travelled . First disconnection I saw when I passed 200 meters from home. After that I got my laptop reconnected back to hotspot for few-second-sessions.

I have attached the screenshot of the tethering settings page, about 4-5 minutes since I left home. That time I was about 3 km away from home, that was at least 5th session, and the last one.

After that screenshot my laptop finally disconnected until I got back home.
Phone: Huawei P9 Lite (not rooted), laptop: Vaio VPC.

What that was?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This is an interesting observation, but I don't know what to make of this..if you left the phone home....then the laptop continues to connect....quite strange I must say

Comment: Could you access the Internet through the hotspot even when you were several kilometers away?

Answer (score 0):

xavier_fakera, thank you for your edits and for the time allotted to the post.

Speaking that my laptop following me I meant I had the only thought about how that could happened and that was that someone (the person who was left at home) just took my laptop and following me by another taxi (actually moto-rickshaw). But thinking about reasons why that person may want to do that and understanding ability to that's person to get a rickshaw at that place and at that time (5 am) right when I had left home, I still tend to think that there was a some bug in Android. But even being a programmer for the last 20 years, I find it difficult to imagine how such a bug can be reproduced. Something like a cached ghost of my laptop ... But there were a few re-connections to the hotspot. Each re-connection is a verification of keys and other handshakes. WPA2-Personal connection is not such a trivial thing that could happened accidentally with cached... yes with cached what? With some object that can sign a package with it's private key to make that connection possible?

Comment: Zackary, I didn't try to send my phone far away from my home to personally test is there any connection to the Internet from laptop. But what I actually know that the person who staying at home when I leave it is very not happy at that moment since my phone's hotspot is the only way to have a connection to Internet.